# How to authenticate with GitHub when using a shared machine

Tags: github, access-token

My current workflow includes typing the password. Log into a server, pull (or sometimes clone, checkout or even push), type in the creds and leave. I do not want to store my credentials on that machine and I do not always have the chance to access my own password manager on the same machine.

How are we supposed to do this after a password can no longer be used with GitHub on the command line? Should I actually carry a paper slip with an access token? Or am I obliged to configure SSH deploy key for every project on every server? It seems to require logging into github website and it's not like I have a GUI on those machines.

Is there any sane way? How would you do it, if you sit down in front of a linux bash and have to deploy a project on that machine, using that machine?

Answer (score 0):

How you should handle this depends on what your needs are.

If you want to automate a deployment process for a machine, then using a deploy key for that machine is a good idea, since that's the exact purpose for which they're designed.  Ideally your deployment processes *are* automated, and deploy keys are a good way to do that.

If your goal is to log into several machines via SSH and perform Git operations with a remote, you can use an SSH key.  If you're logging in via SSH, then add your SSH key to your agent and forward your agent to the remote system with the `-A` option, which will let you perform the access as if you had that key on the remote system.  This is the easiest and simplest solution if you can do so, and is even more convenient than typing your username and password.

If you need to log in to machines at the console, then generate an SSH key, add it to GitHub, and store it on a flash drive, at which point you can mount the flash drive and use the keys with Git by setting the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -oIdentitiesOnly=yes -i /mnt/path-to-key` (substituting the path to the key).